# Save applied formats of conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I add conditional formatting to the Excel file:

```
Sub Apply_Conditional_Formatting()
With Sheet1.Range("=$1:$1048576")
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=$A1=$F$1"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
End With
End Sub
```

I want, once the conditional formatting is applied, the formatting of the sheet is saved and the conditional formatting is deleted.

Something like if you Copy&Paste as values to eliminate the formulas in an Excel cell.

In the example above the yellow lines RGB(255,255,0) that are applied to the sheet should **remain** even if the `conditional formatting` is deleted afterwards.
[image]

Comment: Is there any special reason to do it by `VBA`? You can do it easily by regular conditional formatting.

Comment: Yeah, it should be in VBA because the above VBA is part of longer procedure with multiple other VBAs.

Comment: As an aside, perhaps look at the UsedRange property of Worksheet ... you are setting the formats for a massive range otherwise. And why use conditional formatting at all, if you are just going to throw it away? Why not loop through the Rows() in UsedRange, apply the test in VBA and then set the colour of the row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the current applied color (and other format settings that you can set via conditional formatting) via the `DisplayFormat`-properties of a cell.

The following code will copy the color that is currently set to a cell by conditional formatting so that it remains after deleting the conditional formatting:

```
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        cell.Interior.Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: How do I have to modify your answer if the conditional formatting is only applied to Sheet1.Range("A$1:C$7") and only for this range the conditional format should remain after deleting it.

Comment: Just define the range in  the `For`-Loop, eg `For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C7")