# Hard coding the effects of conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba, function, conditional-formatting

I have found a solution to hard code the effects of conditional formatting and it works to a certain extent. The original code is attached and my adapted code is also attached. My adapted code now hard codes colour and patterns but I cannot get it to work for gradient colours.

Original (This works but my needs require patterns and gradients to also be included)
Source :[Save applied formats of conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64276835/save-applied-formats-of-conditional-formatting)

```
'this block will hard code the applied conditional formatting
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        cell.Interior.Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    End If
Next cell
```

I have adapted this to also hard code patterns which works. But hard coding gradients does not work.
This bit that doesn't work is surrounded by the comment.

```
'this block will hard code the applied conditional formatting
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        With cell.Interior
            .Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
            .Pattern = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Pattern
            '*********** THIS BIT DOESN'T WORK**************
            .Gradient.Degree = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Gradient.Degree
            '.Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
            With Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                .Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).Color
                .TintAndShade = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).TintAndShade
            End With
            With Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                .Color = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color
                .TintAndShade = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).TintAndShade
            End With
            '*********** THIS BIT DOESN'T WORK**************
        End With
    End If
Next cell
```

Any help to get me to a solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Apologies I was not aware that I could undelete. I also did not see the answer before I deleted the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `With .Gradient` a dot is needed to qualify its parent object
- `Add` is a method, use `ColorStops(1).Color` to get the value of property

```
For Each cell In rng
    If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
        Set CFInte = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior
        With cell.Interior
            .Color = CFInte.Color
            .Pattern = CFInte.Pattern
            Set CFGrad = CFInte.Gradient
            .Gradient.Degree = CFGrad.Degree
            '.Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
            With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                .Color = CFGrad.ColorStops(1).Color
                .TintAndShade = CFGrad.ColorStops(1).TintAndShade
            End With
            With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                .Color = CFGrad.ColorStops(2).Color
                .TintAndShade = CFGrad.ColorStops(2).TintAndShade
            End With
        End With
    End If
Next cell
```